# Connecting a YII ajaxButton to a controller to execute server side functions?

Tags: yii

I have the following button:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
  'label'=>'myLabel',
  'buttonType'=>'ajaxButton', 
  'url'=>'someUrl', 
  'type'=>'primary', // null, 'primary', 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'danger' or 'inverse'
  'size'=>'small', // null, 'large', 'small' or 'mini'
  'ajaxOptions'=>array(
      'type' => 'POST',
      'beforeSend' => '
        function( request ) {
          //alert(request);
        }'
      ,
      'success' => 'function( data ) {
          //alert(data);
        }'
      ,
      'data' => array( 
        'actionName' => "INCREMENT"
      )
  ),
)); ?>
```

So, the tricky part is, how do I connect this button to actual backend code? I would assume it's done by posting to a URL. In my case I've got a URL set as:

```
'url'=>'someUrl'
```

Does this mean I must create a view, controller and model so there is a URL to post to? isn't there an easier way without going through that effort?

Comment: which view has this button? which controller renders this view? what is this button supposed to do (roughly)? edit: this button has to be within a view, have you thought about which view it should belong to?

Comment: View => this is in main.php (the frontpage). Controller --> sitecontroller. Button does --> it increments a field in the database. Should be very straight forward. First prize is if I can get the button to execute a public function in the controller?

Comment: I am starting off by trying to figure out how to increment the value. Once i can do that, the javascript to update the front should be easy...

Comment: you have got a url set, what is it? where does it lead to?

Comment: Url set? What do you mean? The tricky part for me is WHERE to post to? I would like to post to a URL that will return a "N" for a fail, and a "Y" for a success, without showing the rest of the layout. Does this mean I need to create a new view, or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not necessarily need a new view. But you will need an action that *catches* this request.

In Yii each action has a unique url that refers to it, and there are functions that generate such a url for us, [namely `createUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail). There are other versions of `createUrl` also, the one here is from `CController`.

So you'd modify your url property as:

```php
'url'=>$this->createUrl('controller-name/action-name')
```

Then in your controller add the action:

```php
public function actionActionname(){
    // do your server-side stuff
    // maybe also return some message back to client-side view
    if(success)
        echo "Y";
    else echo "N";
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```